# Listing only regular files, problem with stat

Tags: c, posix

I want to list regular files in a directory. However, `stat` fails for every file.

```
DIR* dp = NULL;
struct dirent* entry = NULL;
dp = opendir(directory);

if (!dp) { log_err("Could not open directory"); return -1; }

while (entry = readdir(dp))
{
    struct stat s;
    char path[1024]; path[0] = 0;
    strcat(path, directory);
    strcat(path, entry->d_name);

    int status = 0;

    if (status = stat(path, &s))
    {
        if (S_ISREG(s.st_mode))
        {
            printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't stat: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
}

closedir(dp);
```

The output is

> Can't stat: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable
>
> Can't stat: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable
>
> Can't stat: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable
>
> (... many times)

`errno` is set to `E_AGAIN` (11).

Now, if I printf the resulting `path`, they are indeed valid file and directory names. The directory is readable, the user I run with does have the rights to do so (it's the directory where I write the program in).

What is causing this problem, and how can I do this correctly?

Comment: Have you checked that execute permission is allowed on all of the directories in path that lead to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stat` and many other system calls return `0` on success and `-1` on failure. You are incorrectly testing the return value of `stat`.

Your code should be:

```
if (!stat(path, &s))
{
    if (S_ISREG(s.st_mode))
    {
        printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
    }
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't stat: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a delimitier.

```
strcat(path, directory);
strcat(path, "/"); //this is missing
strcat(path, entry->d_name);
```

Don't forget to account for the extra '/' when allocating your string.